# Nginx and ReactJS - refreshing page gives 404

Tags: reactjs, nginx

In my index page (url = ../web/), I redirect the users to the login page (url = ../Login) if they are not logged in. This works fine. However, if I refresh the page, I get a 404.

None of other files are listed under "sources" in Chrome Developer tools.

I was thinking it was perhaps something to do with Nginx not properly loading the files. Some of my .conf file is below

```
location / {
    root  /home/vagrant/site/mednax/ProfessionalApp;
    try_files $uri /index.html $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
     autoindex off;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  }
location ~ \.php$ {
```

Comment: try giving try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

Comment: have you tried it?